# VBA Run-time error 438 appears when "paste" runs

Tags: vba, excel, paste

I'm just getting familiar with VBA and my code

```
For k = 3 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(k).Activate
ActiveSheet.Cells(11, 2).Select

lLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
ActiveSheet.Range("A5:" & "A" & CStr(lLastRow)).Copy
' ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells("B" & CStr(lFirstRow) & ":B" & CStr(lLastRow)).Select
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Activate
ActiveSheet.Cells(lFirstRow, 2).Select
Selection.Paste
'Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
'Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
lFirstRow = lFirstRow + lLastRow
Next k
```

makes "Run-time error 438. Object doesn't support this porperty or method" to appear when the line "Selection.Paste" goes. What's the problem?:(
I've tried to use paste special, to activate sheet and to select cell (not range), to use Cstr, but nothing changed

Comment: Range object doesn't suppor method `Paste`. Use `ActiveSheet.Range("A5:" & "A" & CStr(lLastRow)).Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(lFirstRow, 2)`

Comment: Try replacing `Selection.Paste` with `Activesheet.Paste`

Comment: tnx guys, you are the best

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll`

`Paste` by itself works on several objects, most notably `Worksheet` but not on a `Range` object which is what your `Selection` is.

To paste to a `Range` you really have to use the `PasteSpecial` method with its' available arguements such as `xlPasteAll`; `xlPasteValues`; `xlPasteFormulas`; `xlPasteFormats` and others which you can see by pressing `F1` while the cursor is within `PasteSpecial` in the VBE.

Answer (score 1):

Replace these two lines in your code

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(lFirstRow, 2).Select
Selection.Paste
```

by

```
Cells(lFirstRow, 2).Select
Activesheet.paste
```

your code will work flawlessly

---

Important note for working with paste and pastespecial in vba

Copy any range from anywhere then

1. Paste Special method (`Sheets.Cells/Range.PasteSpecial`)

   Sheets ("Daily Shortage").Activate

   Sheets ("Daily Shortage").Cells (m, 1). PasteSpecial Paste: = xlPasteValues

One Example –

Will throw error

```
Sheets ("June"). Range ("A10").Select

ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Paste: = xlPasteValues
```

This will work flawlessly

```
Sheets ("June"). Range ("A10").PasteSpecial Paste: = xlPasteValues
```

2. Paste method (`ActiveSheet.Paste`)

   Sheets ("June"). Range ("A10").Select

   ActiveSheet.Paste