# Why Selection paste is not working on VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a basic macro that i cant get working.

The last question i asked was closed down as a duplicate but the answers to the other question did not solve mine. [See question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22193723/vba-run-time-error-438-appears-when-paste-runs)

Basically i have a sheet (Live Data) that is connected to the database and is filtered. I want to select any rows that are still visible after the filter is applied and paste the rows to the bottom of another page (Master Sheet). I then filter the mater sheet.

When i run the macro an error appears at the selection.Paste line

```
Sub AddNewRow()

Sheets("Live Data").Select
Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
Selection.Copy
Application.CutCopyMode = False


Sheets("Master Sheet").Select
Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
Selection.Paste

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Master Sheet").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Master Sheet").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key _
    :=Range("C1:C5877"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, _
    DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Master Sheet").AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: "When i run the macro an error appears at the selection.Paste line" -- what is the error? It might help if you were more specific.

Comment: Why are you selecting/copying *all visible cells* on a sheet? Seems like more than you want. You probably want something like `Sheets("LiveData").UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`

Comment: Furthermore: `Application.CutCopyMode = False` will clear the clipboard, so that there is nothing *to* Paste (or to `PasteSpecial`).  You need to remove that line.